# How can I get the childs appended in the xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I would like to modify the XML by adding below mentioned tags in the existing XML:

```
<filter>
<filterName>FOUND_IN_BUILD</filterName>
<operator>
<name>Equals</name>
</operator>
<value>2</value>
</filter>
```

I am trying using the following code :

```
XmlNode FIB_filter = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "filter", null);
//XmlNode FIB_filtername = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "filterName", "FOUND_IN_BUILD");
XmlNode FIB_filtername = doc.CreateElement("filterName");
FIB_filtername.InnerText = ("FOUND_IN_BUILD");
XmlNode FIB_operator = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "operator", null);
//XmlNode FIB_name = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "operator", "Equals");
XmlNode FIB_name = doc.CreateElement("operator");
FIB_name.InnerText = ("Equals");
XmlNode FIB_value = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "value", null);
```

but i am getting the following response:

```
<filter>
<filterName>
FOUND_IN_BUILD
<operator>
<operator>
Equals
<value/>
</operator>
</operator>
</filterName>
</filter>
```

Please help and suggest me to perform the desired operation as i am new to the xml functionality for C#.

My initial XML is as follows:

```
<criteria>
        <includeFilterSets>
          <filterSet>
            <filter>
              <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
              <operator>
                <name>Equals</name>
              </operator>
              <value>Dr.Watson</value>
            </filter>
          </filterSet>
        </includeFilterSets>
        <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
        <entityToSearch>
          <name>BUG</name>
        </entityToSearch>
      </criteria>
```

and the response what i am looking for is as follows:

```
<criteria>
<includeFilterSets>
<filterSet>
<filter>
<filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
<operator>
<name>Equals</name>
</operator>
<value>Dr.Watson</value>
</filter>
<filter>
<filterName>FOUND_IN_BUILD</filterName>
<operator>
<name>Equals</name>
</operator>
<value>2</value>
</filter>
</filterSet>
</includeFilterSets>
<caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
<entityToSearch>
<name>BUG</name>
</entityToSearch>
</criteria>
```

Comment: Can you post your initial xml and the expected one?

Comment: @I4V Thanks. I have posted the initial and expected xml.Please refer.

Answer (score 1):

I find [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) easier to use.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fName);
var filterset = xDoc.Root.Element("includeFilterSets").Element("filterSet");
var filter = new XElement("filter", 
                    new XElement("filterName","FOUND_IN_BUILD"),
                    new XElement("operator",new XElement("name","Equals")),
                    new XElement("value",2)
                    );

filterset.Add(filter);
string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

**EDIT**

And a hybrid code :)

```
var filter = new XElement("filter", 
                    new XElement("filterName","FOUND_IN_BUILD"),
                    new XElement("operator",new XElement("name","Equals")),
                    new XElement("value",2)
                    );

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fName);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//includeFilterSets/filterSet");
node.CreateNavigator().AppendChild(filter.CreateReader());
doc.Save(fName + ".new.xml");
```

Comment: actually i have a limitation here.I am performing these edits in a xml document which is as follows:XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            I have to perform it that way as i have to use this process later in my code.

Comment: is there any modifications required to my existing code so that i can achieve the desired xml.

Comment: Can i do it with some modifications in my existing code i am using.